# Cloudinary React not adding width and height attributes to img tag

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

If I use something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Image} from 'cloudinary-react';

export const Logo = () => {
  return (
    <Image
        publicId="logo.png"
        crop="limit"
        width={170}
        height={16}
    />
  );
}

export default Logo;
```

As a result we get

```
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/blablabla/image/upload/c_limit,h_16,w_170/v1/logo.png">
```

No `width` and `height` attributes in `img` tag.

And that's why **Google PageSpeed Insights** complains about many `img` tags on the page:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Comment: The parameters you're passing in the <Image/> refer to Cloudinary transformations that are added to the output URL (c_limit,h_16,w_170) but aren't related to the HTML <img/> tag width/height. If you want to set the <img/> attributes then @Sowam's first code example will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try passing it inline like:

```
  <Image
        publicId="logo.png"
        crop="limit"
        style={{ width: "170px"; height:"16px" }}
    />
```

or you just pass it in quotes:

```
  <Image
    publicId="logo.png"
    crop="limit"
    width="170"
    height="16"
/>
```

so `width="170"` `height="16"` instead `width={170}` `height={16}`

Comment: I tried both of them at the same time
1. Passed `width` and `height` params as string
2. Added style.

Attributes didn't appear, but style attribute appeared in `img` elemeent.
That's not exactly what is needed according to this article, as far as I understand.
https://web.dev/optimize-cls/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown#images-without-dimensions
But PageSpeed Insights seems stopped complaining about logo element.
I'll experiment with other image elements too.
Thanks.